# Facebook authors user.credential returning nil

Tags: ios, oauth, swift4

Hi I am building an iOS app using swift 4.2 and everything works fine. While I am trying to test all scenarios, when I try to connect through Facebook auth, there will be a push message notification saying

> “your app” wants to use “Facebook.com” to sign in.

Well if I press continue it work fine but if I press cancel my

```
Let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken:FBSDKAcessToken. Current().tokenString)
```

is returning `nil`. I tried to unwrap but it didn’t work. Anyone knows how to fix it please. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which is to verify that FBSDKAccessToken.current() is not nil before creating the credential variable